# Define two controller inside angularjs and use pug call data

Tags: angularjs, pug

I want to define 2 controllers (read 2 json) inside 1 js file. And use pug file call back data from 2 json. My code below:

```
angular.module('shop-menu.controller', []).controller("Shop-menuController", _shopmenuController)

function _shopmenuController($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET', // POST, PUT, DELETE
        url: '../db/shop-menu.json',
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = eval(response.data.data);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('error 003 - Shop: ' + error);
    });
    // $scope.loadlist = function(){
    //  console.log("1")
    // }
}
function _shopController($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET', // POST, PUT, DELETE
        url: '../db/shop-list.json',
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = eval(response.data.data);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('error 003 - Shop: ' + error);
    });
}
```

pug file:

```
.row(ng-controller="_shopmenuController")
    ul.list-inline(ng-repeat="phuong in data") 
    li(ng-click="loadlist")
            a.nav-link {{phuong.name}}
.row(ng-controller="_shopController")
    ul.list-inline(ng-repeat="tam in data") 
    li(ng-click="loadlist")
            a.nav-link {{tam.name}}
```

Please help me!
Thank you

Comment: I think you can request the data using $http.get  `'../db/shop-menu.json'` and `'../db/shop-list.json'` one by one serially using $q promise and callback function, I think it is possible and definitely help you...

Comment: could you show me example code or link document about that function?

Comment: I already have given the enough information, you have to learn like how to use and return $q(function(resolve, reject) promise with $http.get or post method and handle the promise response in callback function. If you are seeking example google it, already SO have so many replies...

Comment: Thank you. But seem it is difficult for me